# Identify specific file of "file" type

Tags: python, filesystems

I have a small script that will identify all of the file type, more specific the extensions.
It runs correctly, not allowing duplicates, only adding to a list the extensios, but the files of the type:`file` can't be identified, so I get in return the names of the files.
As it has no extension I am not sure how to identify them, or sort them.
Could you please advise how to identify the specific file type? Thank you
Here is my code:

```
import os

ListFiles = os.walk(os.getcwd())
SplitTypes = []
for walk_output in ListFiles:
    for file_name in walk_output[-1]:
        type = file_name.split(".")[-1]
        if type in SplitTypes:
            pass
        else:
            SplitTypes.append(file_name.split(".")[-1])

print(SplitTypes)
```

[image: Example]

My output:

```
['849C9593-D756-4E56-8D6E-42412F2A707B', 'ini', 'jpg', 'txt', 'zip', '#TODO', 'py', 'iml']
```

The item at index 0 is a file as given in the photo added for example, as well as the element `'#TODO'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file` type would have no extensions. If you do not want file names in the list, you could use `os.path.splitext` and it would add `''` in the list specifying the missing extension:

```
ListFiles = os.walk(os.getcwd())
SplitTypes = []
for walk_output in ListFiles:
    for file_name in walk_output[-1]:
        filename,ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        if ext in SplitTypes:
            pass
        else:
            SplitTypes.append(ext)

print(SplitTypes)
```

You would get an output like:
`['.csv', '.jpg', '.py', '.txt', '']`

If you want to see all **file** type files in the directory, you can match the extension with `''`

Answer (score 2):

you can check `if len(file_name.split('.')) > 1`

if you'd like to check some tuple of types

```
types = ('.jpg', '.png')
if any(t in file_name for t in types):
    pass
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this will pass also the files that have the extension ".c" or ".h" even if I tried with >= 1, but thank you for taking your time

Comment: I have now seen the edit, and yes, further in the project I presume that I will create a tuple of these extensions, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

All file extension have magic numbers. With magic numbers you can understand a file's file extension. For example, if you open a file without extension but  in fact the file is "PDF" format.. you don't know its extension whenever you open. Using magic numbers for PDF file, if it is starting with "25 50 44 46" hex signatures you can understand this file is a "pdf". [Some of important file signatures is here](https://www.wikizero.pro/index.php?q=aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvTGlzdF9vZl9maWxlX3NpZ25hdHVyZXM).

Comment: The question is about identifying a specifile file type.